# logic question about conditional statements

Tags: logic

Sentence 1: "I will go running only if it is sunny outside........ only if my muscles are not sore.

To me this means: Only if my muscles are not sore, THEN (I will go running only if it is sunny outside).

If my muscles are not sore, then I can still go running, however, the requirement of it being sunny in order for me to go running is no longer present.

Is this correct logic?

Or does the sentence mean: I will go running only if it is sunny outside AND only if my muscles are not sore?

What is the scope of the first "if statement"? Can the second "if" statement nest into the first "if" statement?

I will go running only if (it is sunny outside only if my muscles are not sore). The statement in the parenthesis needs to be true in order for me to go running. Can this logic be inferred from the statement "I will go running only if it is sunny outside......only if my muscles are not sore." ?

Comment: I think this is more of an English usage question than a logic question.  If someone said this to me, I would figure that they mean  your second version  (i.e. they require both not sore muscles and sun).  Mathematically, however, I think your first version would be more likely.  But ordinary speech doesn't strictly adhere to the rules of logic.

Comment: Would a "nested" interpretation be a plausable interpretation or "English" just does not work that way with subordinate clauses nested within subordinate clauses?

Comment: Oh, it's plausible, but I expect people would avoid the inherent ambiguity.  Maybe something like "If my muscles are in good shape then I go running, but only on sunny days."

Comment: To stress:  I don't know how most people would parse the sentence you wrote. As I said, I'd personally lean towards the second reading but I wouldn't be at all surprised if others disagreed.

Comment: This may help: $A$ only if $B$" is logically equivalent to "if $A$ then $B$."